# Why can't Matlab solve this marginal integral involving two independent variables?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve a probability problem using Matlab. The problem is to calculate the marginal probability function for `x` and `y`.

`f(x,y) = y*exp(-y*(1+x))` when x,y belong to (0,inf); otherwise f(x,y) = 0.

```
clear
syms x y f(x,y) g(x) h(y)
f = y*exp(-y*(1+x))
c = int(f,y,0,inf) %% <---- problem here, can't find x,y independent
%%
g=exp(1+x) %% <---- marginal integral should be this.
```

Comment: Why do you think that the integral should evaluate to `exp(1+x)`? One thing you should do is use [assumptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.assume.html): `syms x y positive;f=y*exp(-y*(1+x));` ... Matlab treats all symbolic variables as complex by default.

Comment: Is `f(x,y)` a 2-D distribution? Are you trying to integrate over both values?